# Laravel foreach returns signle index

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I am trying to get users voted games and my query is this

```
$game = Games::where('slug', $slug)->where('id', $id)->with('votes')->first();
```

Games Model

```
public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Votes');
}
```

$game->votes

```js
[
{
id: 2,
games_id: 2,
users_id: 3,
vote: 1
},
{
id: 6,
games_id: 2,
users_id: 4,
vote: 0
},
{
id: 7,
games_id: 2,
users_id: 5,
vote: 1
},
{
id: 8,
games_id: 2,
users_id: 6,
vote: 1
},
{
id: 9,
games_id: 2,
users_id: 1,
vote: 1
}
]
```

has this data

I will calculate these voted datas and
when I foreach this  datas

```
foreach($game->votes as $val) {
    return $val;
}
```

I got only one index

```js
{
id: 2,
games_id: 2,
users_id: 3,
vote: 1
}
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong in this query or in loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is something wrong with your loop. :) This is your loop right now:

```
foreach($game->votes as $val) {

     return $val;

}
```

The [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement immediately ends the execution of your function so when you do that, you are effectively ending the loop after its first loop. You can do things inside the loop like `echo`ing out data. However, a `return` statement will finish that function.

Comment: ohh , yes thats true , after 10 hours coding this kind of things happen :D thank you

Comment: It happens to all of us. :)

Comment: @ErmanSinanTuran I would also recommend taking a look at Joseph Silber's answer if you are simply counting the votes.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the total votes directly from the database:

```php
$count = Vote::whereHas('game', function ($query) use ($id, $slug) {
    $query->where(compact('id', 'slug'));
})->count();
```

No need for any loops.